# Django can StdImageField replace default variation?

Tags: python, django, image-processing, django-models

I have existing Django-based project with some files uploaded.

I need to add a feature to automatically resize new uploaded files to some resolution (200x200). I found a nice library [django-stdimage](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage) that does what I need.

But on upload it stores original file with its original resolution. And existing code works with the original file instead of resized one.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), max_length=64)
    image = StdImageField(upload_to='product_images/', verbose_name=_('Image'), blank=True, null=True,
                          variations={'default': (200, 200)})
```

I would like to save processed files by the same name as original file. I do not need original file by the way.

I do not want to change all the code where it works with image field - there are complex DRF serializers, some views, forms, templates, etc.

So I would like to get new resized image as before by using `myproduct.image` - in templates for example.

Is it possible to do without subclassing `StdImageField` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a [ticket](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage/issues/78) on the StdImage's page and received an answer..

> No, I'm sorry, but nether would this work, nor would I advice you to
>   do such a thing. It would add implicit behavior. That's something you
>   might want to avoid long term.
>
> You can always overwrite the field tho and implement your own
>   behavior. The StdImage code base should be good guidance to implement
>   your own behavior.